# Datatables.net scroll issue in jquery dialog in IE

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-dialog

i'm using the [datatable](http://datatables.net) plugin, i am rendering the datatable in a dialog. inside firefox the datatable is appearing nicely over dialog. But in IE datatable is not at all displaying properly. in IE scrollbar is coming for dialog not for datatable, the whole UI is looking ugly, eventhough the table width grows beyond the dialog width and height, scrollbar is not at all appearing.

Here is my code.

var myplaceholder= $("#placeholder");

```
myplaceholder.setTemplateURL("/Templates/people/makechoice.htm");

    myplaceholder.load("/Templates/people/makechoice.htm", function () {

var ot = $("#Datatable").dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                 { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [0] },
                 { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [1] },
                 { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [2] },
                 { "sWidth": "40%", "aTargets": [3]}],

            "bJQueryUI": true,

            "bFilter": false,

      "sScrollY": "600",
      "sScrollX": "100%",
      "sScrollXInner": "400%",
      "bScrollCollapse": true,

            "bPaginate": false,
            "bProcessing": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "/People/Makechoice",
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "Searchfilter", "value": searchString });
            },
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "oTableTools": {
                "sRowSelect": "multi",
                "aButtons": []

            },
            "bDestroy": true,


            "sDom": 'T<"clear">frtp',
            "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {

            }


        });

    });
```

Here is my Aspx div in which i'm rendering the datatable

```
 <div id="placeholder" style="width:320px">
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you specify the IE version?

Comment: Hi in IE 8 standard mode it works fine, but in IE 8 compatibility view only, the problem is happening

Comment: Depending on your DOCTYPE, a rendering mode that isn't supported by jQuery (i.e. IE5) and thus datatables might get used, more info @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

Comment: so, now what do i need to do for getting rendered in IE8 standard mode? is there any workaround?, any hint or suggestion from your end

Comment: Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you can, if that still doesn't put your IE to standards mode, add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` as the *very first tag* within `<head>` (won't work if it's not the first).

Comment: your solution worked, thanks. i did it like this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=8" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was compatibility issue, refer for more info http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

Just added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=8" />` in site.master,it worked